# How to change principals of already logged in user programmatically?

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, servlets, userprincipal

Im using Java, CDI, JSF.
In my LoginModule implementation i authenticate user and in `commit()` method assigning user principals to Subject object. 
Now, when user is logged in I would like to change its principals without re-logging and then show some other content/options - how can I do that? Is it possible?

I have tried to get current Subject object, it froced me to enable SecurityManager and provide security grants, otherwise Subject is null.

```
AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();
Subject thisSubject = Subject.getSubject(acc);
```

So first - i dont want to enable SecurityManager to get Subject object(am I really need it? maybe theres some kind of bypass?).

Second - how can I change principals programmatically when user is already logged in?

Thank you.